# Why https://console.cron-job.org raise '504 Gateway Timeout'

Tags: next.js, cron, vercel

When I do a test call ti my website, got an 504 error in https://console.cron-job.org, why?

I even did set up CORS to avaind any issues.

Seems that the endpoint is triggered, but then why not response is seen by https://console.cron-job.org?

```
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next'
import { prepareAndSendInvoices } from 'services/sendInvoices'
import { sendWelcomeMessages } from 'services/sendWelcomeMessages'
import { sendMessageToWaitingList } from 'services/sendMessageToWaitingList'
import { connectToDatabase } from 'lib/connectToDatabase'
import { Db } from 'mongodb'

export default async function handler(
    req: NextApiRequest,
    res: NextApiResponse
) {
    const { mongoClient } = await connectToDatabase()
    const db: Db = mongoClient.db('tikex')
    await db.collection('logs').insertOne({
        api: 'processPaymentTasks',
        createdAt: new Date(),
        severity: 'log',
    })
    await prepareAndSendInvoices({ db })
    await db.collection('logs').insertOne({
        api: 'processPaymentTasks > sendWelcomeMessages',
        createdAt: new Date(),
        severity: 'log',
    })
    await sendWelcomeMessages({ db })
    await db.collection('logs').insertOne({
        api: 'processPaymentTasks > sendMessageToWaitingList',
        createdAt: new Date(),
        severity: 'log',
    })
    await sendMessageToWaitingList({ db })
    return res.status(200).end()
}

//-
```